# How to create raster from points classified as ground using external Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, las, error-000732

I am writing a Python script that I want to run outside of ArcGIS Pro. I want it to import a LAS, classify the ground points and then create a DEM using only the ground points. The code I have written below creates a LAS dataset and classifies the ground points as expected. It is there I get stuck. I can't get it to use only the classified ground points to create the raster. I've tried using the 'Make LAS Dataset Layer' tool but I can't seem to reference this layer in the external script. It doesn't appear to be in the geodatabase. As such I am getting an error trying to make a raster from this layer.
Not sure if it's relevant but I am using PyCharm to write the script.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\DSM_Processing.gdb"  # enter path and name of geodatabase workspace here

#First make las dataset from pointcloud
arcpy.management.CreateLasDataset(r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.las",
                                  r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.lasd", "NO_RECURSION", None,
                                  "PROJCS['British_National_Grid',GEOGCS['GCS_OSGB_1936',"
                                  "DATUM['D_OSGB_1936',SPHEROID['Airy_1830',6377563.396,299.3249646]],"
                                  "PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],"
                                  "PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],"
                                  "PARAMETER['False_Easting',400000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',-100000.0],"
                                  "PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-2.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996012717],"
                                  "PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',49.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]",
                                  "COMPUTE_STATS", "ABSOLUTE_PATHS", "NO_FILES")




##Classify the ground surface

arcpy.ddd.ClassifyLasGround(r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.lasd", "AGGRESSIVE", "RECLASSIFY_GROUND", None, "COMPUTE_STATS", "DEFAULT", None, "PROCESS_EXTENT")

##make a layer from from the points classified as ground
arcpy.management.MakeLasDatasetLayer(r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.lasd", "Pointcloud_LasDatasetLayer", "2", "'Last Return'", "EXCLUDE_UNFLAGGED",
                                     "EXCLUDE_SYNTHETIC", "EXCLUDE_KEYPOINT", "EXCLUDE_WITHHELD", None, "INCLUDE_OVERLAP")

#Make raster from layer
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster(r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud_LasDatasetLayer", r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.tif",
                                   "ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 0.1, 1)
```

I get the following error

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input LAS Dataset: Dataset C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud_LasDatasetLayer does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (LasDatasetToRaster).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a LAYER object using the tool MakeLasDatasetLayer() you are not making a DATASET.

So change this line:

```
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster(r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud_LasDatasetLayer", r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.tif","ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 0.1, 1)
```

To:

```
arcpy.conversion.LasDatasetToRaster("Pointcloud_LasDatasetLayer", r"C:\Tool\DSM_Processing\Pointcloud_Data\Pointcloud.tif","ELEVATION", "BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", "FLOAT", "CELLSIZE", 0.1, 1)
```